# Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead: after fitting the model

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I don't understand where i'm getting wrong. Both of the arrays are of same shape and has same no. of elements. i'm getting - "Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample."

I'll provide my code below -

```
y_pred:
    array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1,
           1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
           0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1,
           0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1,
           0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1,
           1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,
           1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1,
           1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
           1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
           0, 1], dtype=int64)
   

 y_pred.shape - (200,)
    
   
 y_test :array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,
           1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1,
           0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1,
           0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0,
           0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1,
           1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,
           0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1,
           1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0,
           1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
           0, 1], dtype=int64)
    

y_test.shape -  (200,)
```

Now when i tried to evaluate this `(dtc.score(y_test,y_pred_dtr))` , I'm getting this error  -

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
    array=[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.
     0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1.
     1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0.
     0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.
     0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.
     1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1.
     0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1.
     0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.
     0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.].
    

Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a
single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Comment: When your are doing dtc.score(y_test, y_pred_dtr). When did you obtained y_pred_dtr? I only see y_pred. Also, I can see that you don't obtain a normal array, values are no separated by commas. I don't know if its an error of copying the output

Comment: @AlexSerraMarrugat I did  : y_pred = dtc.predict(x_test). this is how i got value of y_pred.

Comment: Yes, but in your score you write: y_pred_dtr. This a variable you haven't defined yet. Can you check it?

Comment: @AlexSerraMarrugat i wrote that by mistake in the comment , i calculated the y_pred_dtr

Comment: How many features you have?

Comment: @AlexSerraMarrugat I have 4 features and one label. I'm building a model which predicts whether its a fake news or not .

Answer (score 1):

```
here is the thing,
a=np.array([1,2,3]) is 1D array
now in y_pred and y_test it should be 
array=np.array([sample1array,sample2array,....])
so it should be,
a=np.array([[1],[2],[3]])
so try reshape(-1,1) so
np.array([1,2,3]) will be converted 'n' rows '1' column array (2D) = np.array([[1],[2],[3]]).
try this.
```

EDIT:
because it may be possible that your output length is greater than 1 then? ,like  y=[[1,0],[0,0],[1,0]]. this is the only way to do that. thanks.

Comment: I understood that but i have to reshape both the arrays ? also why do we need 2D arrays for evaluating the score of model ?

Comment: sorry but no, both the array are of same shape , i have mentioned that in the question . Both the arrays are 1D and have 200 values in it.